# joint density and independence

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

if $(X,Y)$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f_{X,Y}$ is said to be its joint density if $\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in A) = \int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy$ for all reasonable sets A.
 Now I have to show that if $(X,Y)$ with density $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ for a pair of non negative functions f anf g, then X has density $f/\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t) dt$ and Y has density $g/\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t) dt$ and X and Y are indep.

So far I know that I have to show that $\mathbb{P}((X \in A) \cap (Y \in B)) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)\mathbb{P}(Y \in B)$. 
So to get $f_x$ I integrate over y, but I don't understand why we have t?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that 
$$
1=P((X,Y)\in\mathbb{R}^2)=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y)\,\mathrm dy\right)
$$
and hence $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(y)\,\mathrm dy=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^{-1}$. Thus, for any Borel set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
P(X\in A)=P((X,Y)\in A\times \mathbb{R})=\left(\int_A f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(y)\,\mathrm dy\right)=\int_A f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
with $f_X(x)=f(x)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^{-1}$, which shows that $X$ has density $f_X$. We argue similarly for $Y$.

As for the independence, you need to use that $P(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\})=P((X,Y)\in A\times B)$ and then use similar arguments as above.